# How many pairs of wire to use for Power over Ethernet?

Tags: power, dc, ethernet

I have a custom setup to supply power over Ethernet cables. I used a pair to connect to a telephone and another pair for power. The device needs 12 Volts at 0.5Amps to run. In normal setups, which usually have devices that need 24 Volts to run I see 2 pairs (4 wires) being used to supply the power. Is it ok to have just 1 pair running to my device to supply the power with a DC terminator that  I am using?

[image: Current setup]

Comment: The wires depicted are not color-coded like unshielded paired wiring (cat5 etc) so this seems to be a nonstandard installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the total resistance the line will have. You may not transmit sufficient power at that voltage, that is where that easy solution is highly considerable; doubling the wires, halfing the resistance :-) If they are not in use for any other thing, I recommend to use them anyway.

It is about its yet unknown power requirements of -after regulator- circuits and design of regulators it have. But simply, observe the device if it has tolerance or not for that amount of resistance given. I mean if everything are OK on all circumstances, different modes etc. I said use the all pairs anyway, because you may not encounter all the power states it will have at that time. So, briefly; if it works with single pair, use two pairs and you are fine. If it works fine only after using two pairs, observe it a longer time. If there is failure, than you have to calculate and make the voltage sufficiently higher on the line and use a buck converter for nominal voltage before the load.

Somebody might say it wouldn't be that much problem for 10-15 m cable; the resistance of ethernet cables are not standart. There has been cables I had seen even as high as 1 Ohm/meter.

Comment: that pair is just in use for powering the device. 12 volts. the cable is approximately 8 - 10 metres